# How to read data values from different rows from an Excel file in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

Essentially I just need to have lookup functionality. I need to go row by row and then access values from other rows in my excel document. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Does your row have unique key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to use two tFileInputExcel components, and use one as a lookup in a tMap, using Left Join/Inner Join between columns to get your corresponding values.

Comment: How does it know which rows to look at in the tMap? I can’t find any examples of this online.

Comment: https://help.talend.com/reader/~Dhe9Vej4Bk9zGrBM4kxQA/Nwh5YQ~BB0ASb7v5zl_Wyw